# How to use latest JHipster version to generate my app?

Tags: jhipster

I'm not (yet) familiar with the javascript stack but I'd like to use JHipster [latest commit](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commits/master) from master to generate my webapp.

How do I build locally `generator-jhipster` project and use it with `yo jhipster`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `npm link` [1](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-link.html) for that:

```
git clone git@github.com:jhipster/generator-jhipster.git
cd generator-jhipster
npm link
```

it will create a globally-installed symbolic link.
You can then use the generator on your system normally.
`yo jhipster`

Answer (score -2):

just use it 
1. sudo apt-get update 
2.sudo npm install -g generator-jhipster

please before install jhipster confirm you have used sudo apt-get update
then it will work 100% 
Thank you